# Цикл for внутри событии click в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Составил такой код:

```
jQuery(".tcarusel-next").on("click",
  function(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
      console.log(i);
      jQuery(".tcarusel-next").click();
    }});
```

Рассчитывал при каждом клике будет срабатывать 5 нажатий (т.е. событий `click`), но вместо этого идет бесконечный цикл.
Что делать, чтобы срабатывал так, как нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myFlag = false;
jQuery(".tcarusel-next").on("click", function() {
  if (myFlag)
    return;
  myFlag = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i); 
    jQuery(".tcarusel-next").click();
  }

  myFlag = false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Хотелось бы узнать, для чего служит вот это конструкция:

if (myFlag)
    return;
  myFlag = true;

Насколько я понял благодаря этой конструкции не образуется бесконечный цикл

Comment: @Ilnyr правильно. `myFlag` с значением `true` говорит о том, что код находится внутри цикла, вызывающего клики, и что запускать такой цикл еще раз не следует.